# How to correctly SELECT from subquery yielded table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to execute a `SELECT * FROM WHERE result.usd_equivalent > 10` on a table that is yielded by my subquery. I'm new to this and unsure if I'm writing this correctly but below query gives an error saying `Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'currency'`. I've also set the alias of the subquery as `result`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT *, t.amount / POWER(10,  cd.exponent) * fx.rate AS "usd_equivalent" 
FROM new_schema.transactions t
    JOIN new_schema.fx_rates fx
    ON t.currency = fx.ccy
    JOIN new_schema.currency_details cd
    ON t.currency = cd.currency
    WHERE fx.base_ccy = "USD"
) result
WHERE result.usd_equivalent > 10;`
```

I just want to fetch the rows as per my `WHERE` clause from the yielded table. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Forget about `SELECT *`, list columns one-by-one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, t.amount / POWER(10,  cd.exponent) * fx.rate AS usd_equivalent
FROM new_schema.transactions t
JOIN new_schema.fx_rates fx ON t.currency = fx.ccy
JOIN new_schema.currency_details cd ON t.currency = cd.currency
WHERE fx.base_ccy = "USD"
HAVING usd_equivalent > 10;
```

Comment: Thank you, amazing

Answer (score 1):

The `SELECT *` in your subquery is selecting a column named `currency` from both `new_schema.transactions` and `new_schema.currency_details`, thus resulting in an error.

You need to either only select a single instance of the `currency` column from one of the two tables, or rename both columns to different names.